# android layout creation issue

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Am new to android development. I had created one android app and for that following is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/grid_layout_1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_btn_text"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnRegister" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reg_btn_text"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Am getting the following warning :

```
This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is possibly useless;
transfer the background attribute to the other view
```

Can anyone tell the reason for this warning and a solution to the issue.?

Comment: Nice tips for you here: **[Android SDK Tools: Layout Optimization](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-tools-layout-optimization/)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real usage to have just a LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout. So one of them is useless as this is redundant.

**edit**

This warning is triggered, when a Layout has only one child that is also a Layout. In this case one of both can be removed without any problems. It is recommended to remove these redundant layouts as they reduce the overall performance of the UI.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: The LinearLayout as the only child in the RelativeLayout? Describe me why you need to do that, I am interested :)

Comment: @PareshMayani Please show us since he is right. There is _absolutely_ no reason to have a LinearLayout inside of a RelativeLayout like posed in the question.

Comment: @all : i need to include more elements in the same UI. Its just a moke that am going to create. And at the very first stage itself i got this warning. So i posted the question to get an understanding from you experts about handling multiple layouts.

Comment: What if i want to have two buttons with equal width: Login and Register? At that time we have to take LinearLayout with two buttons having layout_weight="1" and layout_width="0dp".

Comment: @TijoKVarghese if you will add other children to your RelativeLayout, the warning will disappear, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @PareshMayani We talk about a LinearLayout as the only child in a RelativeLayout and not about two buttons in a LinearLayout.

Comment: @WarrenFaith, "there is no real usage" is a very bold thing to say when you have no clue what the OP is doing. Off the top of my head I can think of lots of "real usage". It is probably not really conventional usage, but in UI development you frequently have to get creative, and these sorts of solutions are entirely appropriate, given the right circumstances.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel you might be right, but with the given context it doesnt make sense and I am not good at guessing :)

Comment: In the given context if I just removed the `LinearLayout` I would had to find another way to centre the buttons in the `RelativeLayout`, preferably not on top of each other. Which I find a non-trivial problem as I am new to Android development.

Comment: There are real world usages to having a LinearLayout inside of a RelativeLayout @OctavianDamiean.  Pretty bold to say there is _absolutely_ no reason for it.  One such use would be to have a LinearLayout that sits at the bottom of the screen using the RelativeLayout as a full screen element with layout_alignParentBottom set true while containing other Views.  Like a footer menu that shows/hides overtop of the views already on-screen.

Comment: To be honest. I don't even care anymore since I don't develop for Android any longer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question, as I just discovered myself, is to disable the new Lint "help".  I suppose it's helpful to someone just starting out in Android, but to anyone that knows what they're doing, it's just a nuisance. For example, your "useless" nested linear layout might very well be a button inside a padded layout that might be awaiting being filled by some other element, at run time (or a billion other, entirely valid things).

In your preferences, under android/lint, just disable the warnings and you won't see these warnings anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

`Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking`

Scroll and find `"UselessParent"` option. Change the `severity` option to `Ignore`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when designing my first Android app. I typed everything exactly like it said in the book down to the "T" and double checked everything many times.

My guess it has something to do with the book possibly being out of date but it's only a year old.

I would think the person writing the book would know what they are doing. It's "The Complete Idiot's Guide to Android App Development" 2011.

I'm aware of the lint option but what is the reasoning for using this even though it's useless?