# Layout possibly useless - no it isn't

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, warnings

I'm new to Android development and have created a layout that looks like this:

```
RelativeLayout
   ScrollView
      LinearLayout
         TextView
```

The compiler complains about the ScrollView being "possibly useless". As discussed in [[android layout creation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711878/android-layout-creation-issue]), I could get rid of the warning by putting ScrollView at the top of the hierarchy, removing the redundant RelativeLayout. However, I want to keep the RelativeLayout, because I am going to add more stuff at runtime. Is it possible to tell the compiler that I want to keep this particular layout? Basically, I want to get rid of the warning, but I don't want to disable this kind of warning altogether.

EDIT: Although the full code is irrelevant to the question, here it comes:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainFragment" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/test_right" 
                android:textSize="@dimen/test_right_textsize"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: For clarification: The thing that I want to add at runtime is another ScrollView that is independent of the ScrollView in the layout, i.e. the new ScrollView is supposed to hover on top of the rest, overlapping it, hence the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Please _Paste_ full code of your Layout.

Comment: whatever stuff you are trying to add at runtime is goes under ScrollView Child layout so that why Relative Layout redundant.

Comment: No, I don't want to have the stuff I added scrolled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the warning in

```
Windows -> Preferences -> android -> Lint -> UselessParent
```

change it's Severity to ignore

Edit : you can insert code below at the root of your layout

```
tools:ignore="UselessParent"
```

Comment: Please read my question in full. I told you I don't want to disable this kind of warnings altogether.

Comment: @digorydoo : sorry for that plz see the edited answer

Comment: Cool, that seems to be the thing I want. However, the compiler complains about the attribute "uselessparent" being missing in the Android namespace.

Comment: found it! instead of <lint>, I had to add the attribute tools:ignore="UselessParent" in the ScrollView. Warning gone! Put this into your answer, then I can put the checkmark. Thx!